# Laravel 5.3 Commented out @extends('layout.app') still takes effect and includes as display

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using PHPStorm as IDE for creating Laravel pages. I actually just started learning it. However, I noticed that even if I comment out the `@extends('layout.app')` like `{{--@extends('layout.app')--}}` somehow it still reads the html and includes the `app.blade.php` as display on the browser.

To better explain, here are the codes.

**Controller.php**

```
public function showContactPage()
{
    $people = ['Hello', 'World', 'Ashton', 'Alvin'];
    return view('contact', compact('people')); 
}
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blade Templating Sample</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    @yield('content')
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**contact.blade.php**

```
{{--@extends('layout.app')--}}

@section('content')
    <h1>Contact Page</h1>

    @if(count($people))
        <ul>
            @foreach($people as $person)
                <li>{{$person}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif

@stop
```

**Output on browser**

[image]

**View Page Source codes**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blade Templating Sample</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
        <h1>Contact Page</h1>
            <ul>
                 <li>Hello</li>
                 <li>World</li>
                 <li>Ashton</li>
                 <li>Alvin</li>
            </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you look on the page sources `html` code, it still shows what's in app.blade.php even if I commented out the `{{--@extends('layout.app')--}}` in `contact.blade.php`

I don't know if it's an issue with PHPStorm or the browser or if it is something I should expect as result after commenting out the `@extends`

Or maybe with **Laravel 5.3**

I'd appreciate any thoughts or explanation to this.

Thank you.

Comment: Clear view cache. `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @Console Thansk for the suggestion. However, I tried entering the command on terminal which executed successfully, went to the browser (both Firefox and Chrome) but still got the same display.

Comment: if this above dosen't work then get to the `storage/views` directory and delete everything except `.gitignore`. You probably dosn't has the right rigths to this directory so mayby you'll have to use `sudo`